# Omnisharp not loading properly - Visual Studio Code and Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

When I try to open a unity script in vscode, I get an error message `Some projects have trouble loading. Please review the output for more details.`. When I select `Show Output`, I get this output:

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 7/5/2022, 6:09:26 PM
    Target: /Users/angelalindsay/Desktop/Unity Projects/First Unity Game/First Unity Game/First Unity Game.sln

OmniSharp server started with .NET 6.0.301
.
    Path: /Users/angelalindsay/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.0-darwin-x64/.omnisharp/1.39.0-net6.0/OmniSharp.dll
    PID: 2949

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on Unknown 0.0 (Unknown)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        Checking the 'DOTNET_ROOT' environment variable to find a .NET SDK
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        Using the 'dotnet' on the PATH.
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 1 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: .NET Core SDK 6.0.301 17.2.0 - "/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.301/"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: .NET Core SDK 6.0.301 17.2.0 - "/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.301/"
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpFormattingWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        Detecting projects in '/Users/angelalindsay/Desktop/Unity Projects/First Unity Game/First Unity Game/First Unity Game.sln'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for '/Users/angelalindsay/Desktop/Unity Projects/First Unity Game/First Unity Game/Assembly-CSharp.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Detecting CSX files in '/Users/angelalindsay/Desktop/Unity Projects/First Unity Game/First Unity Game'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Did not find any CSX files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Configuration finished.
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location '/Users/angelalindsay/Desktop/Unity Projects/First Unity Game/First Unity Game' on host 2915.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: /Users/angelalindsay/Desktop/Unity Projects/First Unity Game/First Unity Game/Assembly-CSharp.csproj
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        This project targets .NET version that requires reference assemblies that are not installed (e.g. .NET Framework). The most common solution is to make sure Mono is fully updated on your machine (https://mono-project.com/download/) and that you are running the .NET Framework build of OmniSharp (e.g. 'omnisharp.useModernNet': false in C# Extension for VS Code).
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file '/Users/angelalindsay/Desktop/Unity Projects/First Unity Game/First Unity Game/Assembly-CSharp.csproj'.
/Users/angelalindsay/Desktop/Unity Projects/First Unity Game/First Unity Game/Assembly-CSharp.csproj
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.301/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1221,5): Error: This project targets .NET version that requires reference assemblies that are not installed (e.g. .NET Framework). The most common solution is to make sure Mono is fully updated on your machine (https://mono-project.com/download/) and that you are running the .NET Framework build of OmniSharp (e.g. 'omnisharp.useModernNet': false in C# Extension for VS Code).

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attempted to update project that is not loaded: /Users/angelalindsay/Desktop/Unity Projects/First Unity Game/First Unity Game/Assembly-CSharp.csproj
[warn]: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.InlayHints.InlayHintService
        Inlay hints requested for document not in workspace Location { FileName = /Users/angelalindsay/Desktop/Unity Projects/First Unity Game/First Unity Game/Assets/Scripts/WayPointFollower.cs, Range = Range { Start = Point { Line = 0, Column = 0 }, End = Point { Line = 21, Column = 0 } } }
[warn]: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.InlayHints.InlayHintService
        Inlay hints requested for document not in workspace Location { FileName = /Users/angelalindsay/Desktop/Unity Projects/First Unity Game/First Unity Game/Assets/Scripts/WayPointFollower.cs, Range = Range { Start = Point { Line = 0, Column = 0 }, End = Point { Line = 21, Column = 0 } } }
```

I don't know if this is related or not but, the autocomplete for unity is not working in vscode either. I'm able to type code and it works in unity but I would like to have autocomplete and get rid of this error message. Can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a Linux distro?

Comment: No, macOS Big Sur V11.4

Comment: OSX is a Unix based OS so this might help: [Forum Answer](https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-unity-with-vs-code-and-intellisense-on-linux-mint.986088/) I had a similar (same?) issue when installing on Ubuntu

Comment: @akaBase Do I have to do step #1 if I already have vscode installed already?

Comment: No, I was using VSCode

Comment: Ok. I don't see the "Omnisharp: Use Global Mono" setting for step #4. Could it go by a different name on my machine? This is the only step I haven't done and nothing is fixed.

Comment: It should be an option, and I dont have an OSX machine anymore to look sorry

Answer (score 1):

> This project targets .NET version that requires reference assemblies
> that are not installed (e.g. .NET Framework). The most common solution
> is to make sure Mono is fully updated on your machine
> (https://mono-project.com/download/) and that you are running the .NET
> Framework build of OmniSharp (e.g. 'omnisharp.useModernNet': false in
> C# Extension for VS Code).

**"Can I fix this?"**

Yes, just set `omnisharp.useModernNet` property to false.

Comment: How do I now turn on auto-complete? Thanks.

Comment: I installed mono, set `omnisharp.useModernNet` false, quit vs code, then opened the script from unity. It worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem as the console says (thanks for pointing me to check omnisharp's console) is that you don't have the version of .NET which the `omnisharp` plugin expects.

I solved the issue by installing older version of the extension as mu project was using .NET 5 and the updated version of the extension was searching for .NET 6.

I am not sure if you can set the .NET version per project - probably but didn't find a way.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem on my Mac and eventually, I managed to fix it by following these steps:

1. Disable the `omnisharp.useModernNet` property by setting it to false.

   - Initially, I encountered a strange error related to some exe
     files, despite using an M1 Apple Mac.
   - Eventually, I realized that resolving the issue solely through changing settings was unlikely.
2. Remove all C#-related extensions and reset all settings.
3. Repeat step 1 by setting `omnisharp.useModernNet` to false again.

After performing these steps, the problem was resolved!

> It's worth noting that during a previous occurrence of this issue, I
> simply had to reinstall the C# extension requirements. For Windows,
> this involved installing the .NET Framework and MSBuild Tools, while
> for macOS/Linux, it required Mono with MSBuild.

- Mono(mac): https://www.mono-project.com/download/preview
- MSBuild Tools(windows): https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2022

I hope this explanation proves helpful to others experiencing a similar problem.